# Java merge sort error? Keep getting input values?

Tags: java, sorting, merge

I am very new to Java sorting algorithms, and I cannot find the error in my merge sort algorithm. The result continually gives me the input array, rather than a sorted result. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public class Mergesort {

    static int [] finalarray = new int[12];

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int [] numbers = {6,10,15,4,30,60,24,90,76,100,120,140};

        int [] tem = new int[12];

        mergesort(numbers, tem, 0, (numbers.length - 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("" +finalarray[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void mergesort(int [] num, int [] temp, int first,int last)
    {
        if (first < last)
        {
            int mid = (first + last) / 2;
            mergesort(num, temp, first,mid);
            mergesort(num, temp, mid + 1, last);
            merge(num,temp,first,mid,last);
        }
    }

    public static void merge(int [] num, int [] temp, int firstpos, int midpos, int lastpos)
    {
        int half1begin = firstpos;
        int half1end = midpos;
        int half2begin = midpos + 1;
        int half2end = lastpos;
        int numbersIndex = 0;


        while(half1begin <= half1end && half2begin <= half2end)
        {
            if (num[half1begin] <= num[half2begin])
            {
                temp[numbersIndex] = num[half1begin];
                ++half1begin;
            }
            else 
            {
                temp[numbersIndex] = num[half2begin];
                ++half2begin;
            }

            numbersIndex++;
        }

        while(half1begin <= half1end )
        {
            temp[numbersIndex++] = num[half1begin++];
        }

        while(half2begin <= half2end )
        {
            temp[numbersIndex++] = num[half2begin++];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            finalarray[i] = temp[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the merge method to the following:

```
public static void merge(int [] num, int [] temp, int firstpos, int midpos, int lastpos)
{
    int half1begin = firstpos;
    int half2begin = midpos + 1;
    int numbersIndex = firstpos;

    //Copies the original array into the temp array
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      temp[i] = num[i];
    }

    //Copies the smallest value from either side to the original array
    while((half1begin <= midpos) && (half2begin <= lastpos))
    {
      if (temp[half1begin] <= temp[half2begin])
        {
            num[numbersIndex] = temp[half1begin];
            ++half1begin;
        }
        else 
        {
            num[numbersIndex] = temp[half2begin];
            ++half2begin;
        }

        numbersIndex++;
    }
    
    //Copies the rest of the left side of the array into original
    //No need to copy the right side
    while(half1begin <= midpos )
    {
      num[numbersIndex++] = temp[half1begin++];
    }
}
```

The main changes were initialising the temp array each round to the num array, and swapping the orders of num and temp around within the while loops.

The original method you used doesn't work because the array used to compare in the while loops is the exact same each run, so it doesn't do anything.

Also, you don't need to create a new finalarray to store the values;printing it from numbers array in the main method is sufficient. Could look towards using arraycopy to copy to the final array if you prefer, though.

...apologies if I got any of these wrong, since I'm not that well-versed at this either.

[Source](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html#mergesort)